# Delete all posts and associated meta data that are not custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, posts

I want to remove all posts that are not custom post types from the wp_posts table, and along with it delete any related `wp_posts_meta` , `wp_comments` , `wp_comments_meta` and anything related to those posts.

I'm just not sure what syntax to use.

I have a development site that has old data and I'd like to import all post data from the live site before I launch. Everything I'm finding on stackoverflow is about deleting specifically things like authors and their related posts.  I want to delete everything from every author so I can run the import with everything.

Comment: Posts and custom fields are completely different, do you mean "remove all posts that are not custom post types"?

Comment: Sorry, yes.  I meant remove all posts that are not custom post types.

Comment: Create your function with `wp_delete_post()`

Comment: @MattSartori if you found a solution, you may write an answer and accept it. So you'll make the question and answer useful for future readers.

Comment: @NickVolynkin I don't see that I have that option.

Comment: At least I don't see a way to accept the answer from  @PieterGoosen.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @MattSartori you can post an answer to your own question and accept it :-). Just check below the question is an option to post an answer. There is also a badge for that, and you might even score yourself some reputation points if you add a good answer :-)